# Is there any good jquery plugin for html to pdf conversion except jsPDF

Tags: jquery, html, pdf

I tried jsPDF but the content is rendering fine in Chrome but losing in Acrobat. Is there  any good html to pdf conversion plugin in jQuery?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org) before, worked well for me. Licensed under MIT so no cost too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following jQUery plugin for **HTML** to **PDF** conversion except **jsPDF**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf

This plugin has many options which you can use.

Answer (score -1):

We have a jQuery plugin called "jqchart" for HTML to PDF Conversion

http://www.jqchart.com/jquery/gauges/SegmentedDisplay/ExportToPdf